# AGImagePickerController difficulty

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

So I'm using the `AGImagePickerController` in iPad, I successfully save my selected image in `NSDocumentDirectory`, and load it into an array. The `AGImagePickerController` is in my `UIButton`, so when it is clicked the picker shows up. But what my problem is, how to maintain the **checkmark** on the selected image even when I go to another `viewcontroller`. Thankyou.

Comment: do you mean if you go back and select another library? or completely dismissing the `AGImagePickerController`, open another controller and then open the AGIP again?

Comment: Both or either of what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for this, yet, but I can add it in a matter of time.

Comment: Sure I'll wait for it. Hope you could help me. Thanks

Comment: @Artur thanks for response =) ( … he's the author of the library ;) )

Comment: Yup. Nice project by the way!

Comment: Done. Thanks! Glad you like it :)

Comment: What do you mean done? Its so useful better than elcImagePicker :)

Comment: I have check you repo. And test it. was working on mine, but a little buggy. When on the same `ViewController1` the checkmark stays, but when I go to another `ViewController2` the back to `ViewController1` its gone. I'm using storyboard so I put the `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` part in the `awakeFromNib`. What am I doing wrong? help me please.

Comment: Maybe you don't persist your selection. When you go to ViewController2 the selection array from ViewController1 is deallocated.

Comment: So what can I do to maintain it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to maintain a dictionary or a hash-map for the images which is marked or unmarked separately.

And when your pop up appears you have to redraw all the check-marks which are marked and unmarked corresponding to the NSDictionary images which are present their as a key.

I have also used same type of technique in one of my project.

I hope this works for you and in case if you want code snippet, please let me know.

Comment: Yes how about some snippet, this could help